# Android LinearLayout parent with 3 children, 1 with a weight, another with a fixed width and the last dynamic

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have a form in my android app made up of a parent LinearLayout that is oriented vertically, with a bunch of children that are oriented horizontally. The children have a label (TextView) and then an EditText. The LinearLayout that wraps each form row is set to have a width of match_parent so it fills the width of the screen. The inner form row layouts which contain the label and edit text are sized 30% label, 70% text field. I have one field though which has a label (textview), edit text, and then another text view on the same line. I want the label to keep 30% space, have the last text view at the end of that line to be fixed, and the edittext to take the remaining space. here is a sample of the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <LinearLayout style="@style/FormRow">
        <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/Username"          
           style="@style/FormRowLabel"
           android:text="@string/username_hint"
    />
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/UsernameValue"         
        style="@style/FormRowEditText"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    />
</LinearLayout>
.....

<LinearLayout style="@style/FormRow">
        <TextView 
           android:id="@+id/AnotherField"          
               style="@style/FormRowLabel"
               android:text="@string/fieldname"
            />
    <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/AnotherFieldValue"         
        style="@style/FormRowEditText"
        android:width="?"
                    />

         <TextView layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sometext"
            />
      </LinearLayout>                   

</LinearLayout>
```

My styles look like so:

```
  <style name="FormRow">
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">6dp</item>
        <item name="android:weightSum">10</item>
    </style>
    <style name="FormRowLabel">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">3</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">false</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    </style>

    <style name="FormRowEditText" parent="EditText">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">7</item>
    </style>
```

I've played around with using weights for all 3 but in landscape orientation I end up with a bunch of waisted space for the text view that could be used for the edittext. Is there any way to do this with layout weights? Or how else could I do this? I"m not a big fan of relative layout so I'd prefer to keep these inner layouts as LinearLayouts.

Comment: Have you tried TableLayout?

Comment: I think the [Table API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html) will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem you're having, and in order to achieve what you want, you'll have to change the way you've architected it.

Let's create two columns, instead of rows. The first column will have all of the labels, and the second column will have the `EditText` views, and the occasional `EditText` + `TextView`.

**Example:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if you have any problems!

Comment: Hmm interesting solution. The issue with making 2 vertical columns would be alignment of things in the left and right column vertically. I think a table layout is probably the best way to do this.

Comment: Not necessarily. Using gravity, you can achieve whatever you require.

Comment: I'm confused how elements with a height set to wrap content would line up in 2 separate views if the heights of the inner elements aren't the same? Some of my labels on the left are 2 lines depending on the language and it works fine now but I fail to see how they would work especially if I don't know ahead of times which will wrap such that I can give extra padding in the right column to the corresponding element. I would have to use fixed height rows I would think for this to work and I'd rather not do that.

Comment: I see, you're correct. It could be quite cumbersome. Tables may be better for what you're doing. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it possible. Here is how I did:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/abcd"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@drawable/selection_on_higlight"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/efg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hij"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:text="x 99"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cartItemName"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/lmn"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/cartItemSubtotal"
        android:src="@drawable/broccoli"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cartItemQty"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/xyz"
        android:text="abcd"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|right"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Just set the width attribute as match parent and specify the weights accordingly